# What is the difference between OnShow and OnLoad in World of Warcraft?

Tags: lua, onload, handlers, world-of-warcraft

This may sound like a very obvious question but I am using the OnShow script handler for a frame and it seems to take effect when the frame Loads as well as when it shows so I do not understand why I should ever need to use OnLoad for a frame. It shows when it loads and it loads before it shows but does that really matter?

Is there some sort of major distinction between the two that I am unaware of?

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any, just a game (World of Warcraft) to make AddOns :/

Comment: http://wowprogramming.com/docs/scripts/OnShow and http://wowprogramming.com/docs/scripts/OnLoad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnShow` is called, when the frame becomes visisble. A frame can be created without being visible. Thus, `OnShow` won't be called. `OnLoad` will be, on the other hand.

`OnLoad` is called, as the frame gets created - Not visible, as above.

**Sources:**

http://wowprogramming.com/docs/scripts/OnShow
http://wowprogramming.com/docs/scripts/OnLoad